# Svg file exported from illustrator rendered incorrectly on IE and Edge

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg, export

The svg file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="811.49" height="817.74" viewBox="0 0 811.49 817.74">
  <path class="b" d="M692.4,290.2c5.4-4.2,6.8-11.9,5.3-18.6-1.3-5.6-4.2-10.5-7.3-15.2a13950769914941.89,13950769914941.89,0,0,1-1.2-2l-.6-.9" transform="translate(-199.51 -96.49)"/>
</svg>
```

When rendered in chrome it looks like this:

[image]

and when rendered in microsoft edge it looks like this:

[image]

The illustrator image was drawn manually using paint brush tool. I am guessing the exported svg path coordinates are invalid for microsoft edge so how to export this correctly for IE and microsoft edge?

I am looking for a solution which our designer will be able to apply to export his illustrator files to svg without needing a programmer. Its obvious that a specific deletion can solve the specific file problem but I want a more general solution and understanding of the reason for this.

Export options screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you please show us the Illustrator save options window?

Comment: @DanielaJagher I added a screenshot of the export options in the bottom of original post

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'z' at the end of the 'd' command:

```
<path d="... z" />
```

Z command closes a path.

Comment: I asked for a non-programmatic solution that our designer can configure to export correctly from illustrator.

Comment: @GuyL. There are no such options in the exporter. Illustrator just does what it does you have no control over this. Though in this case you can just close the paths in illustrator before export. But this is more like a bug in IE and edge than in the export itself.

Comment: @joojaa how do I tell the designer to: "close the paths in illustrator before export"? because that sounds like what I was looking for. Can you give more details please

Comment: If the Z command closes the path you can easily open the source code of this image and type it in